A context-sensite grammar for the language of sequences of two different types of parentheses with possible intersections?
Consider the language $L$ over the alphabet (,[,),]
such that any word $w \in L$ if formed as a shuffle of two (possible empty) well-formed sequence of parenthesis: one over (,) and another over [,].
Examples:
$$()[\,] \in L;$$
$$(()[\,]) \in L;$$
$$([)] \in L;$$
$$[(][)] \in L;$$
$$[(][([)(])]) \in L.$$
It is well-known that no context-free grammar exist for this language.
Do you know how to write a context-sensitive grammar for $L$?.
I know how to recognize the words from $L$ using a certain pushdown automaton with 2 stacks. But, in general, such automatons are more strong than context-sensitive grammars.

Basically, the idea is that $($ and $)$ can commute with $[$ and $]$, but $($ cannot commute with $)$ – and same for $[$ and $]$.
An essentially noncontracting grammar would be:

$S \to \varepsilon \mid S'$
$S' \to S'S'\mid A_1S'B_1 \mid A_2 S' B_2 \mid A_1B_1 \mid A_2 B_2$
$A_1 \to \, ($
$B_1 \to \, )$
$A_2 \to \, [$
$B_2 \to \, ]$
$A_1A_2 \to A_2A_1$
$A_1B_2 \to B_2A_1$
…

(remaining rules are the same thing for $B_1A_2$, $B_1B_2$, $A_2A_1$, $A_2B_1$, $B_2A_1$, $B_2B_1$).

Merci @Nathaniel, I see the idea, actually, commuting does the thing.

Plus the nesting $S'\to A_i S'B_i$.

@HendrikJan Of course! I had forgotten these rules. Thanks for noticing.
